# JavaFX styling list items in accordion titled panes

Tags: css, javafx-2

I've been assigned to apply styles to an existing JavaFX application. I'm running into a snag trying to figure out how to get down to the list items in a titled pane which is in an accordion. This is the .fxml:

```
<Accordion fx:id="availableObjectArea" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
```

The Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for TitledPane states that you can address the first TitledPane through first-titled-pane. Then the substructure of TitledPane is listed as content, which is a StackPane/li:

TitledPane Substructure:

```
•title — HBox
  ◦text — Label/li> 
  ◦arrow-button — StackPane/li> 
  ◾arrow — StackPane
•content — StackPane/li>
```

However, I'm having a hard time getting down to the list item level. This is the most obvious way but does not work:

```
#availableObjectArea > .first-titled-page > .content > .stack-pane > .li {
  -fx-background-color: #707070;
}
```

This assumes that the substructure continues as a parent/child set of entities. I've also tried ".content .stack-pane .li" as just descendants, but again not getting it to work. I've also tried dropping .stack-pane from the hierarchy. Looking for advice on what little picky thing I'm missing (this is my first time trying to style something not browser based.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is simply broken html markup... `<li></li>` is responsible for the bullets... Also the node with the `content` style class IS the `StackPane`.

Comment: Thanks Fabian - I got thrown off by the HTML mistake. If you follow the link to the documentation it's in there, so not just a copy/paste error when creating my question. I spent a number of hours today chasing the <li>. I have access to the code and found that they are using TreeView, so all I have to do is set the style for .tree-cell:selected.